# Compiling C code using gcc and php for multiple input

Tags: php, c, gcc

I am trying to execute the c code using gcc compiler. i have created one dynamic_code.c file and it is like this

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
char ch;
char str[100]; 
printf("Enter any character \n");
scanf("%c", &ch);
printf("Entered character is %c \n", ch);
printf("Enter any string ( upto 100 character ) \n");
scanf("%s", &str);
printf("Entered string is %s \n", str);
}
```

Now using gcc compiler i want to execute it at produce the output. Condition is both input to be passed during compilation time.

Using php

```
 $input = 's world';
 exec("gcc dynamic_code.c -o dynamic_code");
 $string="echo '".$input."' | ./dynamic_code";
 $output=exec($string);
 $json = json_encode($output);
 echo $json;
```

output coming is

```
"Entered string is world"
```

How can i produce

```
Enter any character
Entered character is S
Enter any string ( upto 100 character )
Entered string is world
```

Thanks
Edit:
see this...i want something like this
http://cfiddle.net/jlmKDA

I think the problem is to collect all the output...only last printf output is stored

Comment: So you want to be build an online C compiler?

Comment: not exactly....but something like that

Comment: Try removing the *single* quotes from the `$string` variable.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str);` should be `scanf("%s", str);`

Comment: @devnull not working...same result

Comment: @NemanjaBoric same result from this also

Comment: Are you sure you want to call json_encode on string?

Comment: not required....just want string as output

Answer (score 0):

`$output=exec($string)` will set `$output` to the *last* line from the result of the command.

Use

```
exec($command, $output);
print_r($output);
```

---

If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. ...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php